# How does calculated field value form in pageInfo

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, paging, splistitemcollection

Using paging in **XsltListViewWebPart** there are some rules, which form **pageInfo** attributes and which we can see in the query string. Here is the short example, what I mean.

```
Paged=TRUE&p_SortColumn=SomeValue&p_ID=2&PageFirstRow=3
```

The strange and unpredictable rule, that I noticed, is while using **calculated fields** in sorting. The name of the sort column is formed using the usual rule - `"p_ColumnName"`. But the value has the strange prefix, which consists of the magic number and "_" symbol. Here is the example.

```
Paged=TRUE&p_calculatedColumn1=8_1&p_calculatedColumn2=11_Value1&p_ID=2
```

where the first calculated column has boolean output type, and the second one - text output type. The magic numbers are 8 and 11 accordingly. What are they? What do they mean? How do they form?

There are two steps, that I am absolutely sure in.

1. The magic number is different from the output type of the calculated field.
2. The magic number depends on the number of parameters in the formula of calculated field. But I can't say exactly, what dependence is.

Please, share some information about these magic numbers, if you can.

Comment: You cpuld always dissassemble the SP dlls and look for the code that implements this behavior. To my surprise, a less uncommon practice than I thought, and often the only real way of knowing.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype.aspx

Says a Boolean is value 8

So I don't suspect any magic there